# import into Firebase and create push ID

Tags: json, firebase, import, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way/tool to import a json file containing a list of objects and have Firebase push IDs created for each on one the way in?  What I'd like is for every things in

```
{"Top Things" : 
[{
    "Thingnum": 1,
    "place": "place 1"
  },
  {
    "Thingnum": 2,
    "place": "place 2"
    }]
}
```

to have it's own push ID created.
I've tried firebase-import but it doesn't create push IDs.

Or will I have to write a script?
Cheers

Comment: I don't know of any tools that do it. I would recommend writing a script.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing node scripts.  Some kind of DBAadmin tool would be nice.